# Consume REST API and use response data inside multiple components (Not page)

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a page with multiple components, like tables and displayed in one page.

My +page.svelte:

```html
<script>
.
.
<script>
<div class="page-content">
<Row>
  <Table1 />
  <List /> -->
  <Table2 />
</Row>
</div>
```

My REST API call as an example in one of my component:

```html
<script>
let todos // 'forever' undefined

    async function fetchTodos() {       
        const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/')
        return await response.json()
    }
</script>

{#await fetchTodos() then todos}
    <h1>{todos.length} todos!</h1>
{/await}
```

However if I want to use it inside each tables and some of the data in the List component, according to this solution I need to place the same call all of my component and I generate unnecessary extra same calls.

1. What is the proper way to call the endpoint once and reuse the response data in all components?
2. I want to poll the REST API call in every 15 seconds and refresh the fields inside the component, so saving extra call would be crucial. Any polling solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sharing state I would recommend using a context ([`setContext`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#setcontext)/[`getContext`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#getcontext)), these are available in an entire component sub-tree. E.g. use it in a [layout](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout) that all relevant pages use.

To make the context reactive, you can use a [store](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store).
For polling you can just use `setInterval` but that should be cleaned up once the data is no longer required; stores can have a `StartStopNotifier` to start polling on first subscription and stop on last unsubscribe.

Note that you can also [load data directly in a layout](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#layout-data) which then could be used to initialize the store.

Basic example without initial data:

```js
// lib/data-store.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import { browser } from '$app/environment';

// ...

export function createDataStore() {
  const store = writable(null, (set, update) => {
    if (browser == false)
        return;

    async function getData() {
        const newData = await fetchNewData();
        set(newData); // or use update to e.g. append to existing data
    }

    const handle = setInterval(getData, 5000);
    getData();

    return () => clearInterval(handle);
  });

  return store;
}
```

```html
<!-- +layout.svelte -->
<script>
    import { createDataStore } from '$lib/data-store';
    import { setContext } from 'svelte';

    setContext('data', createDataStore());
</script>

<slot />
```

```
<!-- some component in sub-tree -->
<script>
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';

    const store = getContext('data');
</script>

{$store}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a1c9a577318e4745948b84b485981687?version=4.2.10)

(To keep polling independent of subscribers you can use [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#onmount) to start and its returned function to stop. E.g. if you need a consistent stream of data.)

Comment: wow thank you so much! It's almost working. In my Child component, I see [object Object] on the page, on network tab I see the rest calls, but how can I access all the info inside the object and print out like {data.someting or data.something2}?

Comment: Depends on the shape and type of your data, you can access it like any other object. E.g. `{$store.property}`.

Comment: Ok, your solution works well, thanks:) However with fresh new build, I am able to display the property, but when I refresh I got this error: Avoid calling `fetch` eagerly during server side rendering — put your `fetch` calls inside `onMount` or a `load` function instead
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'propertyName'). I don't have any idea why, but first time same prop works, and crashing with manual refresh. Any idea why?

Comment: As noted, you can get the initial data via a load function, in my example there is an initial `getData();` call that could then be replaced by an argument to `createDataStore` that contains the initial data which is passed to the store. The store is initialized to `null` (`writable(null, ...)`), so unless you change that to some initial value it is **not** safe to access any store properties directly.

Comment: All the data fetching inside the store can be guarded with an `if (browser) { ... }` ([docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment-browser)), to prevent any server-side request during the initial rendering. (*Edit*: added an early return to the example code.)

Comment: Finally found the issue! {#if $store} {/if} was missing around @store. it works now!